List of top research, free and subscription, epub (electronic publication / electronic book), research sites
When I was a student, for each academic subject, there were several academic journals which you could subscribe to, and, the publications were searchable on terminals and made available in paper format in libraries, where the research paper booklets were bound together in sets of twenty or forty or so. Only the research publication titles were searchable on the library terminal. You could also search library books and if they weren't signed out the computer would tell you where on the bookshelf it was available. There were also several research magazines that one could subscribe to fire a fee, either for individual or public reading.
I would expect things have changed since then, and now, I would expect everything to be readable, on my Android device.
However, what are the main sites for academic magazines and publications, nowadays (free or paid)?
Why would one still have to pay to access research (where do the funds raised by this type of access go)?
Thank you for pointing me to references, and, depicting the broad picture, of how to access and read academic material from Android devices.
Perhaps, there are even some broad cross-subject sites.
Thank you for pointing out.
Thanks.

You can get most published stuff from archive.org and scribd
But Google scholar is probably what you're after.
